# Using Random.Next() in a collection/object initializer

Tags: c#, collections, random, initialization

**Can anyone explain why the code below, when run, will occasionally result in some "NULL!" strings being written to the Console window?**

(That's the *TL;DR* question, read on for further details)

This doesn't happen every time and you may need to run this code a few times, but soon enough, you'll see a string of "NULL!" being output to the Console window instead of a number.

Essentially, it's initializing (using the shorthand collection initializer syntax) a generic collection of user-defined types (`List<Thing>`)  that contains a single property which is a reference to another user-defined type (`Numb`).  `Numb` is pre-defined in a collection of it's own (`nnn`) and objects from that collection are created using the shorthand object initializer syntax from *within* the collection initializer using a lambda to select a random object based upon it's sole `num` property.

The `nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()` should never return a `NULL` object (i.e. the default part of `FirstOrDefault()`) as the random number should only ever select either a 1 or a 2, both of which exist within the `nnn` collection.

My suspicions tell me this is something to do with using a call (specifically *multiple* calls) to `rnd.Next()` within an object/collection initializer scenario.

#### The code (run as a console application):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            var nnn = new List<Numb> {
                new Numb() {
                    num = 1
                },
                new Numb() {
                    num = 2
                }
            };

            new List<Thing> {
                new Thing() {
                    numb = nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()
                },
                new Thing() {
                    numb = nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()
                },
                new Thing() {
                    numb = nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()
                },
                new Thing() {
                    numb = nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()
                }
            }.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t.numb!=null ? t.numb.num.ToString() : "NULL!"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Thing
    {
        public Numb numb { get; set; }
    }

    public class Numb
    {
        public int num {get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're generating a different random number on *each test of the predicate*. So just looking at one part:

```
new Thing() {
    numb = nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

That's going to:

- Start iterating, get the first `Numb` - let's call that `n1`
- Generate a random number, 1 or 2 - let's call that `x`
- Check whether `n1.num == x`, and yield it if so
- Assuming the previous step *didn't* match, it will...

  - Continue iterating, getting the second `Number` - let's call that `n2`
  - Generate *another* random number, 1 or 2 - let's call that `y`
  - Check whether `n2.num == y`, and yield it if so
  - Assuming the previous step *didn't* match, it will return null

In other words, you're querying against a moving target. You want to generate *one* random number, then test against that for *all* of the values. (Then repeat for each member of the collection initializer.)

Comment: Makes perfect sense when you see it written down like that. Nice one!

Comment: @Jon Skeet - *Smacks forehead*.  Jon, of course, you're absolutely correct.  Don't know how I didn't spot it myself, but now you've mentioned it, it sticks out like a sore thumb!  Thanks.  Now the question is how to generate that **single** random number _per object initializer within a collection initializer statement_!

Comment: @CraigTP: I'd extract the "get a random `Numb`" into a separate method, which makes life considerably easier.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Indeed.  That's probably the only way to do it.  I was just trying to be too clever and reduce the entire collection generation down to a single statement! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
 numb = nnn.Where(n => n.num==rnd.Next(1,3)).FirstOrDefault()
```

When the rnd happens to generate a `2, 1,` sub-sequence you will be trying to match `1 == 2` and `2 == 1`  and therefore not find any match.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you generate a new random number for each comparison.

So the first one is chosen with probability 1/2, the second one with probability 1/4, and none at all with probability 1/4.